# Updating tables from QGIS to pgAdmin

Tags: qgis, postgresql, qgis-3, update, pgadmin-4

I have created a connection between QGIS (ver. 3.10.1-A Coruña) and PostgreSQL (pgAdmin 4).

Every time I edit/update my table in QGIS I have to delete the table in PostgreSQL and re-import again the updated table from QGIS.

How can I update the table without deleting it?

Comment: there should be a 'live' update of the 'remote' potsgres layer you modify ... you must be doing something wrong ... are you sure you **commit the changes** u make ?

Comment: Yes, there something wrong in the workflow. PostgreSQL is a database server. PgAdmin4 and QGIS are both clients, connected to that database. Can you explain you workflow?